# Doctrine2: fill up related entities after loading main

Tags: lazy-loading, doctrine-orm

There are `HotelComment` and `CommentPhoto` (1:n) - user can add some photos to own comment. I'm loading slice of comments with one query and want load photos to this comments using other query (using `WHERE IN`).

```
$comments = $commentsRepo->findByHotel($hotel);
$comments->loadPhotos(); // of course comments is simple array yet
```

Loading comments needed on demand, not on `PostLoad` event.

So question is: how it possible associate loaded comments with objects of `HotelComment`? Using `ReflectionProperty`: `setAcesseble()` + `setValue()`? Is there simpler sollution? And I'm afraid that `UoW` detects `HotelComment` entities as modified and will send updates to db.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Why don't you just eagerly load the CommentPhoto entities via a join in findByHotel()?

Comment: What kind of context are you dealing with here, just showing a hotel, along with comments and photos to end-users?

Comment: I don't want join photos because besides `CommentPhoto`s presents `CommentVotes` (user can rate hotel by some parameters) and other things. Too much tables to join. + We don't need this photos all the time, as I say - it should be loading on demand.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your relation as "LAZY". See doctrine documentation:

1. [ManyToOne](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone)
2. [ManyToMany](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytomany)
3. [OneToOne](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/annotations-reference.html#onetoone)

Than you'll be able to load it lazily with `$comments->loadPhotos()`, at least documentation [says so](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-lazy-loading)

**UPDATE:** I think you don't have to to something special to avoid your entities flushing to the DB. In fact, when you query your entries with DQL, they have `managed` state, so attaching them to other managed entity's collection does not change their states, so they are not flushed unless you have modified them.

Hovewer, that doesn't help at all, because associations are fetched **before** first usage, so adding an entity to the collection with the following code will result in an implicit database query:

```
$comment->addPhoto($photo);
//in Comment class
function addPhoto(Photo $photo){
    //var_dump(count($this->photos)); //if you have any - they are already here
    $this->photos->add($photo);
}
```

Maybe declaring your collection as public (or that tricks with `ReflectionProperty`) will help fool the Doctrine, but that's a dirty hack, so I haven't even tried them.

Detaching parent entity also doesn't help. I've ran out of ideas for now....

Comment: After this I will get +N queries. I want use one query `WHERE IN`.

Comment: So you want to load your objects with single query and than attach it to managed objects. And you don't want those objects to be flushed to the DB again when you sync, right?

Comment: Have you ideas how to do that?

Comment: Not yet. I have doctrine2 at home, so I'll try to do that later, maybe today's evening.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hydrate the related objects this one time only, and not every time the object is loaded, you need to use DQL:

```
$em->createQuery("SELECT comments, photos FROM HotelComment comments JOIN comments.photos photos");
```

You can put this in a method on the repository.
This will issue a single SELECT statement, with an INNER JOIN to the comment photos table.